# C++: Declaring pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So, in [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) guide I read that saying

```
char * terry;
```

was different from saying

```
char* terry; //or
char *terry; // FYI: I understand what these two do.
```

as stated by

> "I want to emphasize that the asterisk sign (`*`) that we use when
>   declaring a pointer only means that it is a pointer (it is part of its
>   type compound specifier), and should not be confused with the
>   dereference operator that we have seen a bit earlier, but which is
>   also written with an asterisk (`*`). They are simply two different
>   things represented with the same sign."

However I do not understand why. Perhaps I took the quote the wrong way, now that I have read it once again, but I am still confused. Can anyone tell me if this is **wrong or right and why?**

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's your preferred pointer declaration style, and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why)

Comment: Why would the statement that starts with "I want to emphasize..." lead you to conclude what you opened the question with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, all three are exactly the same as far as the parser is concerned.  People certainly have their reasons for using each style, but there's not really a "right" way.  As an editorial note, I prefer:

```
char *terry;
```

What the author of your link is describing is that the `*` in the declaration is somehow different from the unary `*` operator used to dereference a pointer:

```
char *terry = "abcdefg"; // declaration & initialization
*terry = 'x';            // dereference
```

This potential funny business is actually one of the reasons I prefer the notation I mentioned above - it makes both cases look the same, so there's no room for confusion.

Comment: So for what reasons would I use the `char * terry;` style?

Comment: @Yokhen - I wouldn't.  Ever.  You certainly can if you prefer - it makes literally no difference to the compiler.

Comment: I use `char * terry;` as I think it looks good. I also like that I can easier see a difference between this and when dereferencing(using the `*terry = 'x';` style for that). Anyhow it makes no difference at all really...

Answer (score 1):

I think all three are the same
Once you have declared a pointer e.g.

```
int *x;
```

and later on you want to dereference it you'd use

```
*x
```

Answer (score 1):

Textbooks often recommend writing `char *terry` to remind you that in the statement `char *terry, jerry` terry is a pointer but jerry is not. Avoids a noobie mistake.

Others write `char* terry` because they read it as "char-pointer terry." These people probably never declare pointers and non-pointers, or even just two pointers, on the same line. Which is not a bad rule to use.

Otherwise, whitespace almost never matters in C++. Except inside identifiers (variable names, function names) and... can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
char *terry;
```

Just because then if you do something like

```
char *terry, *jerry, larry;
```

It's obvious you forgot a pointer.

Comment: That's one reason **not** to use the second form.

Comment: ...or just be nice and declare them all on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may have misread.

```
char * terry;
char* terry;
char *terry;
```

Are all the same way to declare a char pointer, named terry.

As for the "right" way, that depends on your coding standard. I personally use `char* terry`

Answer (score 0):

he is trying to differentiate  between  the definition `char *terry` and its usage after the definition e.g. `perry = *terry;` where `perry` takes the value of `terry`  rather than the address. As far as compilers  are concerned, and others  have noted in there answers all three definitions are  same.  I prefer `char *terry`,  where asterisk(*) hugs the variable.

Answer (score 0):

char* terry; //or
char *terry;
Simply means you are declaring a pointer of char type.

Now terry hold the address location of a character variable, which you have might asked terry to point.

If you print terry, it will print the memory location.

If you dereference terry ( *terry) you will get the character, it is pointing to.

That is what that write up you are mentioning is telling.